# Substract number from wc cmd in one line

Tags: bash, awk, cat, wc

Let's suppose *test.csv* contains 10 lines. I'd like to put 9 into *output.txt* in one command line.
I tried:

```
cat test.csv | $(wc -l) - 1 > output.txt
```

*output.txt* should contain 9.

Comment: `awk 'END{print NR-1}' test.csv > output.txt`

Comment: What should `output.txt` contain when `wc -l` outputs `0` for an empty file - `-1` or something else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
echo $(( $(wc -l <test.csv) - 1 )) > output.txt
```

or

```
wc -l <test.csv | awk '{$1--}1' > output.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Or just the good old-fashioned:

```
expr $(wc -l < test.csv) - 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this Perl one-liner:

```
perl -le 'print `wc -l <test.csv` - 1' > output.txt
```